# Deployment of Outlook Add-in - no resources / images

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to deploy an Add-in I wrote, but it has trouble finding associated resources - that is, images for the ribbon.

My GetImage-function is this:

```
    Dim path As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(path)
    path = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("\bin")) + "\Resources\" + imageName
    Return New Drawing.Bitmap(path)
```

The reason it fails seems to be that AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory is `C:\Users\MZE\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\4RZKJG5Q.XVT\72NBJ1XY.1QH\andsoon`. So for some reason on publishing the images are not rolled out as resources. I added them via the project properties add resources dialog in Visual Studio.
I have also tried setting build to resources and copy to out in the image properties in Visual Studio.

I would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the images you add to your project are in the Resources section of your solution.

[image: resource menu]

Check the project folder structure for your images.

[image: project tree]

Try the following revised procedure for your `GetImage` function. Use [IntelliSense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2017) to navigate to your images under ``` My.Resources.``resourceName ```. You shouldn't need to reference a path for the images.

```
Public Function GetImage(control As Office.IRibbonControl) As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Try
        Select Case control.Id
            Case "btnYourButton1"
                Return My.Resources.Image1
            Case "btnYourButton2"
                Return My.Resources.Image2
            Case "btnYourButton3"
                Return My.Resources.Image3
            Case Else
                Return Nothing

        End Select

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing

    End Try

End Function
```

Here is the [Microsoft reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/objects/my-resources-object) for the Resources object.